# OnePlus 6t bootloop

Tags: oneplus6t

My OnePlus starts with its normal android animation of the two dots revolving around the red dot but however the two dots freeze and after some time restarts again.

I downloaded the stock rom version 9.0.16 and tried to flash it using `fastboot update /path/to/mystockfile.zip` but it says

```
--------------------------------------------
Bootloader Version...:
Baseband Version.....:
Serial Number........: 1f1887f2
--------------------------------------------
archive does not contain 'android-info.txt'
fastboot: error: could not read android-info.txt
```

Comment: That must be a recovery flashable zip, not meant to be flashed through fastboot.